# Problem with deploying app to firebase and all config files are listed in browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Can someone help me... When I run `firebase deploy` it's deploying my static folder to hosting, but when I open website url in browser and check source files, there all my files with configs and components, tokens for DB as well. It is not safe at all... everybody can view all source files. How I can deploy so that nobody can view config files etc?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI will deploy everything you put in the "public" folder by default.  Once that folder is published, everything is, as you observed, public information.

If you don't want a file to be deployed, you should either remove it from the public folder, or tell the CLI to ignore that file for deployment using the [ignore configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#ignore) in firebase.json.